# Inserting value in 2nd cell based on value in 1st cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a script where as it reads down an entire column starting with E2 and if a cell in that column has a particular value (for this example, let's say A, E, I, O, or U) then it enters a value of "Y" in cell F2, however it continues this pattern until it runs out of filled cells in column E.

I understand the logic of

```
Dim ColE As String

    For ColE = 2 To Rows.Count

    Next i

If E1 = "A" Or "E" Or "I" Or "O" Or "U" Then F2 = "Y"
```

but how do i repeat that say all the way down the entire column of E until it runs out of filled cells in column E

Comment: If a cell **has** a particular, or **is** a particular value? Will the data in `E2` have `abcd`, and therefore an `A`? Or must it *only* be `A`, `E`, ...?

Comment: Has a particular value.

Comment: It would be good to [edit] your question with your initial code attempt. Also, this can be done with a formula.

Comment: Look up `SEARCH()`, show us your attempts. Get the formula and then you can just drag down/double click to fill to the end of the data.

Comment: I am aware of that. However, based on the answer to this questions, I will be adding other If then statements based on other cells. I don't have any code per say. I just have some doodling of the logic. I mean the basic part of if A1 = "A", "E" then A2 = "Y" I get but its the repeating down that I am having trouble with.

Comment: But this is not a code-writing site... :-(

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This isn't a very tricky thing to do, and you should find various ways to at least start tackling the formula on this site, and outside.  If you have a formula or code you've been trying, please post it with the results, and the expected results. (Sample input/output data is always welcome)

Comment: ^^^ If you're stuck, research `InStr` and how to loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy way to implement a list of `OR`'s:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    s1 = "AEIOU"

    For i = 2 To 25
        If Range("E" & i).Value <> "" Then
            If InStr(s1, Range("E" & i).Value) > 0 Then
                Range("F" & i).Value = "Y"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suitable option here is using the select case command with an if-loop

```
for i = 2 to Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row '5 = Column E 
    Select Case Range("E"&i).value
    Case "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"
        Range("F"&i).value
    End Select
next
```

Using Select Case allows you to also give different commands for other inputs in column E and is way easier to handle than if-conditions for your specific requirements.

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row '5
```

This will return the row number of the last entry in the fifth column (column E). You can use it in the for-loop to iterate until the very last row.

Answer (score 1):

### Search Multiple Criteria

- Copy the code into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`).
- Carefully adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub searchMultipleCriteria()
    ' Handle Errors
    Const Proc = "searchMultipleCriteria"
    On Error GoTo cleanError

    ' Define constants.
    Const SheetName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const CriteriaCol As Variant = "E" ' 1 or "A"
    Dim CriteriaVals As Variant: CriteriaVals = Array("A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
    Const ResultCol As Variant = "F"   ' 1 or "A"
    Const ResultVal As String = "Y"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    ' Write values from Criteria Column Range to Criteria Array.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(SheetName)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Columns(CriteriaCol).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo EmptyColumn
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then GoTo NoRange
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, CriteriaCol), rng)
    Dim Criteria As Variant: Criteria = rng.Value

    ' Write values from Result Column Range to Result Array.
    Set rng = rng.Offset(, ws.Columns(ResultCol).Column - rng.Column)
    Dim Result As Variant: Result = rng.Value

    ' Modify values in Result Array.
    Dim i As Long, Curr As Variant
    For i = 1 To UBound(Criteria)
        ' Note: 'Match' is not case-sensitive i.e. A=a...
        Curr = Application.Match(Criteria(i, 1), CriteriaVals, 0)
        If Not IsError(Curr) Then
            Result(i, 1) = ResultVal
        Else ' Maybe you wanna do something here...
            'Result(i, 1) = "N"
        End If
    Next i

    ' Write values from Result Array to Result Range.
    rng.Value = Result

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"

' Revert Settings (not utilized in this Sub)
CleanExit:

Exit Sub

' Not As Planned
EmptyColumn:
    MsgBox "Looking in an empty column to define a range with values!?", _
      vbExclamation, "'" & Proc & "': Empty Column"
    GoTo CleanExit
NoRange:
    MsgBox "Trying to define a range with an ending row lower than " _
      & "the starting row!?", _
      vbExclamation, "'" & Proc & "': No Range"
    GoTo CleanExit
cleanError:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred in '" & Proc & "'!" & vbCr _
      & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbCr & Err.Description, _
      vbCritical, "'" & Proc & "': Unexpected Error"
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo CleanExit
End Sub
```